# Mobiweb sms provider Automatic dlr forwarding

Tags: php, mysql

is there anyone who use mobiweb sms as a provider and if yes, how do you set up the automatic dlr forwarding using http api in PHP??im having trouble of getting response this error always showing up.

- Server response was different than expected! Please check expected
  response value.

the expected response should be 'OK'
im able to send the message but unable to get response of OK to get the report to my script is there anyone who knows how to fix this? Thanks in advace to someone who could help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should perfectly work:

script.php contents:

`<?php
   echo "OK";
?>`

And then, fill in the form the complete URL to your script.php.

[Screen-Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVJx6.png)

In the screenshot, you will notice an Expected Response (in the red circle) field there with the value "OK" pre-filled. That means that MobiWeb's system expects your script to print that value for validation purposes, so the above script.php example which just prints "OK" will be properly recognised as valid.

Then, click the "Set DLR Forwarding URL" button. Then you will be able to switch the DLR forwarding to "Enabled" state (as you can see in the blue circle).

Before the  **echo "OK"** you may introduce your DLR handling logic but don't forget to add as last output the "OK" string (*or any other string you want, but in that case you should also modify the above "Expected Response" field accordingly*).